Get Data from API only when there is some new record added to server
I am working on a project which is API based, I have to get items every time when I open point of sale punching screen.
Api was built by PHP team and I am consuming it in C# (.Net) App.
Problem:
I don't want to hit the server every time to get some items, I have to hit server only when there is some new item added in server (Database).
I tried to find the solution to my problem but no luck
c# how to only get updated objects from web api

You roll some kind of message queue/pub-sub system so you can subscribe to events published by the server that a new product X has been added. If you somhow disconnect or didnt hear about product X in a while, you re-request it and resubscribe to the queue, and restart your timeout timer. At the very least the server could provide an api call that just returns the date of the last product add, which is fast for you to request (no/low payload size) and you can use that to decide if you need to make a heavy call for a lot. For more info read about how HTTP HEAD was originally conceived to work

can anyone refer me some articles regarding my problem?

You have to notify the client from the server that there is new data available, otherwise it won't know when to call. A simple solution is to have a state variable on the client like isSyncNeeded that you set to false on every successful update and that can be turned back to true by a message coming from the server. Or if you can't initiate communication from server to client you can have an endpoint on the server returning the timestamp of last change in data so that clients can call it compare with what they have and if they differ ask for updated data.
